# Installing software and UbuntuOne

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-one, snap

I try to install something from "Software", and then a window pops up, asking me to register at Ubuntu One - this is needed for installing snap packages.

I usually use `apt` from the command line. Is there a way to use the Software Center and/or `snap` without registering somewhere? I'm tired of opening user accounts. Is there a way to use snaps anonymously?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install *some* snap packages from the store, without signing in to an Ubuntu One account, from the command line using `sudo snap install $package`. However, it is up to the developer of the snap if they wish to allow installation of their package without logging in. Having an account logged in or not has no relation to anonymity though (no PII is required to create an account).

Comment: Thank you! Is there an advantage in logging in, either for the user or the developer?

Comment: Yes, or at least there will be when all the features are completed. First feature would be ability to purchase apps which are for sale rather than free. Later features may include remote installation, update notifications, re-installing of previously purchased/installed apps when migrating to a new device, etc… There are many possibilities for such advanced features, which would require a login.